# LibGDX Uncaught RunTime Exception in HTML Deployment

Tags: java, html, gwt, libgdx

I seem to be getting an error when deploying my game to HTML. The menu screen works fine, then the transition to the game screen causes this error.

[image: screen_shot]

*Text from console*:

```
Uncaught java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) gwt$exception: <skipped>: Cannot read property 'get_5' of null
```

The errors seem to pile on by the millisecond as the window is kept open. The game runs perfectly on Desktop (windows and mac), Android, and iPhone. Not sure what's going on. I'm currently using about 6 different sounds, multiple textures/textureAtlas's, no fonts. The only extension I have for the project is the "Tools" extension.

I fixed the previous error I received after compiling HTML using the Reflection class. Not sure what to do about this error though.

This problem is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120018/libgdx-html5-deployment-exception) from a year ago. I took a look at the build.gradle file in my HTML folder, "strict = true" within the compiler struct, so I'm assuming that's okay. My project also uses GL20 so I'm not sure if those solutions are applicable in this case.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Its been long time for this post and also I'm not sure about exact problem you faced here, I had similar exception but to find exact reasons I need to get hands on code.

What I did for my code:
in short: problem can be any `obj.function()` line, since this happens multiple times, I assume its in rendering loop of current screen.

more detail about my issue which I had solved:
I created class `MyActor` extends `Actor`, had a sprite and a `TextureRegion` (current frame from sprite), while creating replica of this object I was setting value for current frame (act method was fetching current frame but draw was getting called before act) and that was giving me similar error.

I'm not sure if this helps or not, do let me know if you make any progress with this.